# 2 DIV elements are not hugging top without any margin applied

Tags: html, css

**Code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <!-- Styling -->
    <style>

    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }

    html,
    body {
      font-family: Arial;
    }

    header,
    section,
    footer {
      margin: 0 1.5% 24px 1.5%;
    }

    .logo img,
    .logo {
      height: 120px;
    }

    header div {
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: left;
      padding-left: 180px;
      padding-right: 180px;
      height: 120px;
    }



    </style>
    <!-- Styling END -->
  </head>
  <body>

    <header>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/nasa-logo-web-rgb.png" alt="">
      </div>


      <div class="Company-Details">
        <p style="Font-Weight: Bold; Font-Size: 20px;">Company Name</p>
        <p>Address 1</p>
        <p>Address 2</p>
        <p>Address 3</p>
      </div>

      <div class="Company-Contact">
        <p>Tel: 132 321</p>
        <p>Fax: 123 132</p>
        <p>Email: technical@gmail.com</p>
        <p>www: www.google.co.uk</p>
      </div>
    </header>

    <section>

    </section>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Question:**

How come, the 2 `Div's` in the screenshot below, are lowered and not hugging the top just like the image? But, instead it has some margin applied, even tho - there is no margin applied.

[image]

**Have tried:**

I thought it would be reasonable adding this line of code `header div {margin: 0;}`.

That didn't work.

I am quite confused to why the 2 divs (center and right) is not hugging the top?

Comment: the 'problem' is logo, as you can see if you use position relative to logo all 2 div will be to the top

Comment: Appreciate your answers guys! - makes a lot of sense now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after some testing
adding **overflow:hidden** to the header div will fix it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <!-- Styling -->
    <style>

    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }

    html,
    body {
      font-family: Arial;
    }

    header,
    section,
    footer {
      margin: 0 1.5% 24px 1.5%;
    }

    .logo img,
    .logo {
      height: 120px;
    }

    header div {
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: left;
      padding-left: 180px;
      padding-right: 180px;
      height: 120px;
overflow:hidden;
    }



    </style>
    <!-- Styling END -->
  </head>
  <body>

    <header>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/nasa-logo-web-rgb.png" alt="">
      </div>


      <div class="Company-Details">
        <p style="Font-Weight: Bold; Font-Size: 20px;">Company Name</p>
        <p>Address 1</p>
        <p>Address 2</p>
        <p>Address 3</p>
      </div>

      <div class="Company-Contact">
        <p>Tel: 132 321</p>
        <p>Fax: 123 132</p>
        <p>Email: technical@gmail.com</p>
        <p>www: www.google.co.uk</p>
      </div>
    </header>

    <section>

    </section>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does overflow do in terms of positioning the element?

Comment: quote from W3School

The overflow property specifies what should happen if content overflows an element's box.

This property specifies whether to clip content or to add scrollbars when an element's content is too big to fit in a specified area.

Note: The overflow property only works for block elements with a specified height.

Comment: if you found the answer helpful i would really appreciate if you mark the answer as correct :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using display: inline-block; you also should add vertical-align property;
code:

```
header div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; // add this line
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 180px;
    padding-right: 180px;
    height: 120px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The content of the non-hugging `<div>`s is aligned to the bottom of your image.

Give the `<div>` elements inside the `<header>` `overflow:hidden` to make the box itself align.

You could also use `float:left` on the `<div>`s instead of `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add display: flex to the header like this

```
header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
```

}

if this is the result you are looking for :)

edit: i forgot also you need to remove display:inline-block; from header div{
} style